# I want to use mongoDb-kafka connectors in my kotlin-gradle project to read events from kafka topic and store is directly to a mongodb collection

Tags: arrays, kotlin, mongodb-kafka-connector

{
"name": "mongo-sink-connector",
"config": {
"connector.class": "org.mongodb.kafka.connect.MongoSinkConnector",
"tasks.max": "1",
"topics": "xyz-external",
"connection.uri": "mongodb://localhost:27017",
"database": "test",
"collection": "sink-source"
}
}

This is my configuration file what code should i write in main.kt to perform this task..i need to do everything in my kotlin code.

My kafka is running on port 29092 and mongo db is running on 27017 in docker container

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.